# How to filter objects by another object's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

i've got this example of code. Data is my current data which i show in view, and selectedOptions is a object that contains currently selected options by keys.

```
const data = {
  names: [
    { key: 1, name: 'Marek' },
    { key: 2, name: 'Marek 2' },
    { key: 3, name: 'Marek 3' },
    { key: 4, name: 'Marek 4' },
  ],
  ages: [
    { key: 1, age: 14 },
    { key: 2, age: 11 },
    { key: 3, age: 17 },
    { key: 4, age: 22 },
    { key: 5, age: 31 },
  ],
};

const selectedOptions = {
  names: [1, 2],
  ages: [4],
};

const showResults = () => {};

showResults();
```

And I need to filter current data to selected options by key.
Final result should be like this:

```
const filteredData = {
  names: [
    { key: 1, name: 'Marek' },
    { key: 2, name: 'Marek 2' },
  ],
  ages: [
    { key: 4, age: 22 },
  ],
};
```

Comment: So what did you try to achieve it?

Comment: `ages:[{key:4, age: 22 }]` should be your expected result for `ages` according to your `selectedOptions `

Comment: As i said above I tried to get the filtered data according to data, final result should be look like above.

Comment: I need method to do that, but I can't write it

Comment: @MarekMarek Have you read ["How do I ask a good question?"](/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: do you read my question? Its all in it

Comment: in order to be less confusing and to emphasize what the OP intends to filter `selectedOptions` should be renamed into `selectedKeyValues`

Comment: sorry guys, just tryna get some help :(

Comment: we are not hating but you gotta understand that stackoverflow is not a free coding service where we do all the job for you, you already showed us what you have, what your expectations are but not your attempt to solve the issue. When you ask a question, you gotta post your attempt to solve the problem yourself and where you are stuck. then we can help you solve the issue

Comment: I was trying to do this that way but it doesnt work const showResults = () => {
  for (const key in data) {
    filteredData[key] = data[key].filter((record: any) =>
      Object.keys(selectedOptions).every((optionKey: any) =>
        selectedOptions[optionKey].some((i) => i === record.key)
      )
    );
  }
};

Comment: Done. const showResults = () => {
  for (const key in data) {
    filteredData[key] = data[key].filter((i) =>
      selectedOptions[key].includes(i.key)
    );
  }
};

Comment: I was trying to do this more complicated way I think, and dont know if includes is good for perfomance

Comment: Sorry guys for all that, fell bad :/

Comment: nah is ok that you used include along with filter to compare 2 arrays

Comment: Thank you guys, and sorry for the problems that i made

Comment: No, all thanks to y'all and sorry for some of the problems

Answer (score 0):

The OP's target data structure not only corresponds to the one of the original data but also repeats itself with the OP's `selectedOptions` which for better understanding will be referred to from now as `selectedKeyValues`.

Thus, since the OP wants to build a new structure similar to the above two mentioned, the OP needs to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of `selectedKeyValues` (FKA `selectedOptions`).

For a better understanding the result of the last mentioned (but first to be performed) task will be logged ...

```js
const selectedKeyValues = {
  names: [1, 2],
  ages: [4],
};
console.log(
  Object
    .entries(selectedKeyValues)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A `map` task now has access to a data entry's key and the array of key-values. Via the key one can access the original data's entry. In case it exists one could build a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)-based lookup for any of said entry's item, based on such an item's `"key"` property.

The advantage of a lookup comes with not needing to always iterate (e.g. via `includes`) the same items array (especially the ones with a huge amount of items) again and again for each item key's value.

The same `map` task then creates and returns an object with a sole property where the name equals the data entry's key, and the value will be an array of filtered original data-entry items where the filtered array is collected via a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enates the looked up (thus matching by key-value) items.

```js
const data = {
  names: [
    { key: 1, name: 'Marek' },
    { key: 2, name: 'Marek 2' },
    { key: 3, name: 'Marek 3' },
    { key: 4, name: 'Marek 4' },
  ],
  ages: [
    { key: 1, age: 14 },
    { key: 2, age: 11 },
    { key: 3, age: 17 },
    { key: 4, age: 22 },
    { key: 5, age: 31 },
  ],
};

const selectedKeyValues = {
  names: [1, 2],
  ages: [4],
};
const selectedData = Object
  .entries(selectedKeyValues)
  .map(([entryKey, valuesOfItemKeys]) => {
  
    const itemLookup = new Map(
      (data[entryKey] ?? [])
        .map((item) => [item.key, item])
    );
    return {
      [ entryKey ]: valuesOfItemKeys
        .reduce((filteredItems, itemKeyValue) => {

          return filteredItems.concat(
            itemLookup.get(itemKeyValue) ?? []
          );
        }, []),
    };
  });

console.log({
  selectedData
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have done it in much easier way like above

Comment: @MarekMarek ... The OP is always encouraged to post the fruits of the OP's own effort. Please share the approach of yours preferably as executable stack snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = {
  names: [
    { key: 1, name: 'Marek' },
    { key: 2, name: 'Marek 2' },
    { key: 3, name: 'Marek 3' },
    { key: 4, name: 'Marek 4' },
  ],
  ages: [
    { key: 1, age: 14 },
    { key: 2, age: 11 },
    { key: 3, age: 17 },
    { key: 4, age: 22 },
    { key: 5, age: 31 },
  ],
};
const selectedOptions = {
  names: [1, 2],
  ages: [4],
};

const filterSelectedDataItems = (data, selectedOptions) => {
  const filteredData = {};

  for (const key in data) {
    filteredData[key] = data[key].filter((i) =>
      selectedOptions[key].includes(i.key)
    );
  }
  return filteredData;
};

const selectedData = filterSelectedDataItems(data, selectedOptions);

console.log({ selectedData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

this works.

Comment: The above approach is not fail safe for various reasons ... 1) `key` in `data` could not exist in `selectedOptions` (it does not get checked) ... 2) In order to build a structure according to the filter criteria one needs to iterate both the `key`s in `selectedOptions` and then each `key`'s related array of key-values. Anything else could lead to incorrect (in terms of completeness) filter results. ... In addition, an `includes` based approach where `includes` runs again and again as part of an outer iteration already is a not well chosen design.

Comment: I understand, I also understand that doing such things on the front-end side with more data should also not happen and we should have some endpoint for such filtering from the backend?  @PeterSeliger

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).